# Create custom glyphicon and add into bootstrap in Yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, glyphicons

**New updates**
my asset file DashboardAsset which was created inside the asset directory. i have several asset files in this directory.

```
   <?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class DashboardAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/dashboard.css',
        'css/transport.css',
    ];
    public $js = [

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

updated folder structure
[image: updated folder structure]

**Calling the transport icon**

[image]

final appearance of the menu 
[image]

Comment: can you tell where is those less and font files in the yii2 folder structure, also where have you included them in css as well as in app ?

Comment: not included anything in the css. how can i do that ?
i call this in sidenav widget 

'items' => [
                            [
                              'url' => '../dashboard/suppliers',
                              'label' => Yii::t('app','Suppliers'), 
                              **'icon'=>'glyphicon transport',**                                
                              'active' => ($currentpage == 'Suppliers')
                            ],

Answer (score 2):

You must define a new asset bundle file for your new fonts. Put your fonts into a folder under `web` called `fonts` and create style file of including web fonts on a file under `css` folder (Please be careful about address of fonts on your css file. It's usually that you must address them as `../fonts/transport.ttf`). Thus your structure is like this:

```
-| web/
 --| fonts/
   --| transport.ttf
   --| transport.eot
   --| transport.svg
   --| transport.woff
 --| css/
   -- transport.css
```

Now define a asset bundle under `assets` folder based on [Defining Asset Bundles - The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#defining-asset-bundles) like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class TransportAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/transport.css',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Now on each view file that you want to use transport glyphicon, register you asset file:

```
<?php
    \app\assets\TransportAsset::register($this);
?>
<!-- Some HTML Code -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i was followed your instruction but unfortunately all the other glyphicon are disappeared from the menu.  i have updated the question

Comment: What's the output of yii debugger?